# Nmap not returning meaningful output

Tags: linux, networking, nmap

So for a security course homework we need to work with `nmap`. So far no problem. It basically just involves mapping a network that has been setup for us, scanning some ports, do some OS and service detection.

However, my machine returns, depending on the command variation for nmap, that either all host `xxx.xxx.xx.0-255` are all up or all down.
The student assistant also had no clue why this was happening. The same commands worked perfecctly on his machine.

Specifically `nmap -sn -r ipaddress/24` took some time, then said that all hosts are down.

We were both connected to the same network, pings to used ip addresses still worked, but outcome didn't match.

If I remeber correctly, he said something about `nmap` not sending pings, but other TCP protocols.

Further, we knew that some host in the range `xxx.xxx.xx.1-20` had to be up. We could neither scan nor OS fingerprint them. It always returned that the host was down. Even at our own IP-address.

I am using `Kali/Linux Rolling 2019.2` and `nmap 7.70`.

What could possibly cause this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: I assume Kali runs in a VM? You could start by getting the VM out of the way, and installing the native variant for `nmap` directly on your computer. This will rule out all problems caused by funny network setup through the VM.

Comment: Kali is my main and only OS. Sorry for the late reply, forgot abou my thread